# Spring/REST not finding jackson json converter

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to start a Spring REST service and I'm getting the following error:

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.myapp.membership.domain.Test
```

Based on the other questions on this topic I gather that I'm either not importing the right dependencies or I haven't set up my getters/setters correctly.

I'm either missing something in those regards or it's something else because I've looked at them extensively and can't find any errors.

URL: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/test` causes the error

**web.xml:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
             version="4.0">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>membership</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>membership</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**membership-servlet.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- As this is the default config file to be loaded it is the one to import the
        other config files -->

        <import resource="membership-data.xml" />

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.membership"/>

        <bean id="memberController" class="com.myapp.membership.web.MemberController">
            <property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**TestController.java**

```java
package com.myapp.membership.web;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import com.myapp.membership.domain.Member;
import com.myapp.membership.domain.Test;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public Test greeting() {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setT("test");
        return t;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```java
package com.myapp.membership.domain;

public class Test {
    public String getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public String t;

}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp.membership</groupId>
    <artifactId>membership</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <url>http://localhost/membership</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.12</source>
                    <target>1.12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>4.0.1</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.9.9.1</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.9.9</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.9.9</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.9.9</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.9.9</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
<!--            <version>9.0.1</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<!--            <version>1.4.199</version>-->
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: it seems you messed up with lot of dependence, `spring-boot-starter-web` consists of Jackson, so you can remove the   `com.fasterxml.jackson`

Comment: @Deadpool that doesn't appear to have worked.

Comment: I will note that if I change the return type to string (and also return a string) it works flawlessly. It's only when I try to return a custom class that it has issues.

Comment: because it is missing some classes, please clean up the dependencies

Comment: Add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum That did it. I could swear I've added that before, but must have deleted it by accident. Thank you. If you want to submit an answer I'll mark it.